# React check how many times a component re-renders

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm working on something and a piece of my code is a bit slow, what I think happens is that the component re-render too many times for no reason.
Is there any way to check how many times a component re-renders in react(or react-native for the matter)?
What i've tried to do is put a `console.log` after the render method and count how many there are but i'm not sure if that would work.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: yes thats what I do usually, just console.log in render method

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`console.log` will work, if you place it within your render function. If you're concerned about a component re-rendering too many times, try extending `React.PureComponent`. Info about `PureComponent` can be found in [React's docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent). You could also look into the `shouldComponentUpdate` method to see if that will help solve your re-rendering. Info about that is also in [their docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was thinking about PureComponent, I'll do that and see if it changes for the better.

Answer (score 17):

you can place `console.count('counter')` in your render function to check this. Here you'll find all the details about **console.count** [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/count)

Answer (score 5):

Better than putting `console.log` in every component is to use this small util

https://github.com/maicki/why-did-you-update

You will be warned in console every time component re-rendered needlessly (e.g. props nor state did change)

Even though it's not maintained anymore it works perfectly.

Best regards

Comment: Now the project that keeps up with the idea is https://github.com/welldone-software/why-did-you-render

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to count renders is to use `console.log` like this:

```
let counter = 0;

const Component = () => {
    
console.log('counting re-renders', (counter += 1));
    
    return (
     <> 
     </>
   ) 
}
```